# Disabling reply link for comments not working

Tags: 8, theming, comments

I would like to disable reply to comment for anonymous user.

I saw on sereval topics that you have to unset

> $variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']

So I ended up adding a preprocess to the .theme file (bartik.theme since I'm using Bartik. Btw I'm using Drupal 8.5.3)

```
function bartik_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    unset($variables['content']['links']['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']);
  }
}
```

Despite that preprocess, I still have the reply link when I'm anonymous. Does anyone has an idea about what's going on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [hook_comment_links_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_links_alter/8.2.x) rather than THEME_preprocess_comment() .Where as [hook_comment_links_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21comment%21comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_links_alter/8.2.x) will render all the comments links before build:

```
function YOURMODULE_comment_links_alter(array &$links, Drupal\comment\CommentInterface $entity, array &$context) {
  if (\Drupal::currentUser()->isAnonymous()) {
    unset($links['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any clue about why the solution I used was not working ?

Comment: I suggest using #access = false instead of unsett `$links['comment']['#links']['comment-reply']['#access'] = FALSE;`instead of unset. Also you might want to implement some sort of access preventing Anon users from replying .. either access hook or form submit validation hook/event

Comment: @Tibo In your solution, it's only getting all the comment content with already rendered links. So in that hook links array will not be present and links will come as rendered under comment.